# Instantiate UI Image Not working

Tags: user-interface, instantiation, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate a UI image in unity 5 to display a players health. I've used a for loop to spawn a new health block image for every 10 health the player has remaining. However, I can't get the image to actually show on screen (it works when I set up the prefab, but as soon as I try to instantiate it through the code it vanishes). The code isn't finished yet as at the moment I understand all the images will stack on top of each other rather than in a row (which will be the finished result) but I want to make sure I can get the images to actually show first before taking this further. Any help would be appreciated!

Things to know:
Player health is set to 100,
Health per icon is set to 10,
I'm using a prefab (health that only contains a UI image component within my canvas.

code:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public int playerStartingHealth;

    public Image healthBarGreen;
    public int healthPerIcon;

    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore ();

        AddPlayerHealth (playerStartingHealth / healthPerIcon);

        StartCoroutine (spawnWaves ());
    }

    public void AddPlayerHealth (int n) {
        for (int i =0; i < n; i++) {
            Instantiate(healthBarGreen.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this 2D? If it is, try looking at which direction your image spawns, it may spawn facing the wrong way (spawns facing 90 degrees away from your camera), therefore not showing the image! :)

Comment: Yes this is 2d. I've tried this and no luck, I've also tried using a transform position using an empty game object and set the new health icon to the transforms position and rotation but it still doesn't show :/

Comment: Try `Instantiate(healthBarGreen);` instead of `Instantiate(healthBarGreen.gameObject);`

Comment: still no good. doesn't seem to be instantiating the object at all. After taking the game out of maximize I can see it's not showing up in the scene hierarchy during play.

Comment: Hmm. If it is not instantiating then the only thing I could suggest is there could be a problem with your for loop (which it doesn't look like there is a problem). I'd suggest debugging your code using `Debug.Log()`, especially in that loop, as well as seeing if you can instantiate that object in a different place or a different object altogether :)

Comment: right. it is instantiating now. i'd put a spelling error in while playing around. however, it still isn't visible, and isn't instantiating as a child of the healthbar object I want it to. Images to show: http://postimg.org/image/kkqvapb2l/ http://postimg.org/image/90xkskfgz/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96868/discussion-between-tom-and-markhughes88).

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a necro, but this post is high on a google search on the subject. Solution:

```
Image newImage = Instantiate(prefabImage, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
newImage.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
newImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero; // your new position here
```